# one to many relationship laravel with multiple foreign key

Tags: laravel, model, one-to-many, relation

I am on a project with Laravel.

I have two database tables that are in a One-To-Many relationship with each other. They are joined by three conditions. How do I model this relationship in Eloquent?

I am not supposed to modify the database schema, since it has to remain backward compatible with other things.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work.
The owning side:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Route extends Model
{
    public function trips()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Trip', 'route_name,source_file', 'route_name,source_file')
    }
}
```

The inverse side:

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    public function routes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Route', 'route_name,source_file', 'route_name,source_file');
    }
}
```

I don't want to use "use Awobaz\Compoships\Compoships;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `hasMany()` and `belongsTo` method the namespace of your models.
Something like `'App\Models\Trip'` or `Trip::class`

```
class Route extends Model
{
    public function trips()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Trip', 'route_name,source_file', 'route_name,source_file')
    }
}
```

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    public function routes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Route', 'route_name,source_file', 'route_name,source_file');
    }
}
```